# Bug when displaying data on a list view VB.Net with MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I recently came up with a problem that wasn't there before. On the list view part of my program, it usually displays the right data. But something happened (and I tried in vain to retrace my steps but I couldn't remember touching the codes of this part), the data on the list view suddenly started not to display properly.

The recent data that I am adding aren't showing up in the list view and instead of being posted in the bottom part of the last successful data entry, it gets inserted in the beginning of the list and it only shows blanks. But whenever I click update the data is there, it just won't display properly on the list view.

Where did I go wrong? Here's my code:

Displaying of data:

```vb
Public Sub LoadPeople()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM employee_table"
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim TABLE As New DataTable
    Dim i As Integer


    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)

    End With

    'Listview fix
    ListView1.Items.Clear()


    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With ListView1
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("id"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("emp_no"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("emp_firstnm"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("emp_midnm"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("emp_lastnm"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("dept1"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("dept2"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("position"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("schedtype"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("date_hired"))
            End With
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Adding of data:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If sConnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        sConnection.ConnectionString = "SERVER = localhost; USERID = root; PASSWORD=; DATABASE = cph;Convert Zero Datetime=True"
        sConnection.Open()
    End If

    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO employee_table(emp_no, emp_firstnm, emp_midnm, emp_lastnm, dept1, dept2, position, schedtype, date_hired) VALUES ('" & txtEmpno.Text & _
        "','" & txtFname.Text & "','" & txtMname.Text & "','" & txtLname.Text & "','" & txtDept1.Text & "','" & txtDept2.Text & "','" & txtPosition.Text & "','" & txtSchedtype.Text & "','" & txtDatehired.Text & "')"
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Connection = sConnection
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    MsgBox("Added new record")
    Dispose()
    Close()

    'Update
    ViewRecord.LoadPeople()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `sConnection` of `LoadPeople` method decleared?

Comment: it is declared after the public class

Comment: an extra SQL statement:  ORDER BY id DESC?
Otherwise maybe the ID's in the table are messed up?

Comment: the id's in the table are fine I think, it is auto_incremented and it is the primary key. but how do you think it got messed up? because I think it did. by the way I fixed it by deleting all of the data on the table but what if it happens again once I publish the system? I want to try to avoid that error and I have no idea why it even came up in the first place.

Comment: I moved it to answer than, are users able to delete rows?

Comment: a) use parameters it will make the code more readadble and protect against SQL injection. b) `ExecuteNonQuery` is a function. look at that to see how many rows are affected.  c) look in the DB itself to see if there are blank rows added d) it is totally unclear what you mean by "instead of posted in the bottom part of the last successful data entry", Blank LV rows might well mean blank DB rows.